# Django: query to select model instances in a ManyToMany relation using set() method in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model for article tags:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
   tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   additional_info = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

My `Article` model has `ManyToMany` relation with `Tag` model.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
```

When writing a article, writer gets to select as many tags as is available. Now, for the serializer to work, I have to use the set() method in the serializer class.

My difficulty is in writing the query to fetch the tags selected while writing the article. I tried this but it's taking all the tags insted of only the selected ones:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.tag.set(Tag.objects.all())
```

What should be the query to fetch the tags selected during writing  the blog only.

Answer (score 0):

In DRF, `update` method of serializer receives `validated_data` param which holds validated info passed in update request.

So, you could probably get article tags by doing smth like: `tags = validated_data['tag']` which you then could use in `instance.tag.set(...)`.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing right up to this point but stuck at what should be the query in the set() method to fetch only selected tags.

Comment: It should be smth like instance.tag.set(*tags)